# fb:multi-friend-selector exclude_ids not working, showing all friends 

Tags: facebook, fbml, xfbml

This is the code:

```
<fb:serverFbml width="650" "margin-left: 10px;" >
        <script type="text/fbml">
<fb:fbml>
<fb:request-form
        action= "<?=$action?>"
        target= "<?=$target?>"
        method= "<?=$method?>"
        invite= <?=$invite?>
        type= "<?=$type?>"
        label = "<?=$label?>"
        content="<?=$content?>"
        exclude_ids = "12312345,2345235"
        >

<fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false" actiontext= "Invite your friends"  rows="5" cols="5" bypass="skip" target="_top" />
</fb:request-form>
</fb:fbml>
</script>
</fb:serverFbml>
```

Everything is being rendered fine, but the FBML is not exluding the IDS mentioned in the parameter exclude_ids, and it is not working in both the normal as well as condensed version of friend selector. Can anyone please help me fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Actually I just found your error, you put the exclude_ids in the request form and not the multi-friend-selector:

`<fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false" actiontext= "Invite your friends"  rows="5" cols="5" bypass="skip" target="_top" exclude_ids="121212232,233423423" />`

---

I believe you made the same error I did before, those ids (`12312345,2345235`) doesnt look like facebook uids, they are too low.

I had the same problem when I introduced the uids as an integer in the database, the uids doesn't fit in an integer and they get corrupted.For storing a fb uid you need a BigInteger.

Comment: those are just example hardcoded ids, my code is not even working with harcoded longer ids, i have checked validity of the ids by fetching data from graph api using those ids, but they dont work here :(

Comment: @DhruvPathak: ok, I just realized whats your problem, you put the exclude_ids in the request and not in the multi-friend_selector

Comment: thanks alot. That is exactly what the bug was. Did not notice this mistake, funny thing is...even you first thought about Big Integers and all instead of first noticing this bug :)

Comment: @DhruvPathak: True, as Occam said, the best solution is usually the simpler... We tend to forget it and go too complex when solving problems